# Where is wrong in the proof ? about convergence in norm and pointwise

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f_k \rightarrow f$ a.e., where $f_k$,$f$ in $L^p$, $1<p<\infty$.

Then,

(1) $|f_k-f|^p \rightarrow 0$

(2) $|f_k-f|^p \leq 2^p (|f_k|^p + |f|^p) \in L^1$ (the dominated function is integrable )

Therefore, $\int |f_k-f|^p \rightarrow 0 $ by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

But, we know that pointwise convergence does not implies $f_k \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$ norm. Where is wrong in my proof.

Thanks

---

LDCT:
If $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $|f_n| \leq |g|$ for some $g \in L^1$. Then
$\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$.

Here $f_n$ is $|f_k-f|^p$  and $g$ is $2^p (|f_k|^p + |f|^p)$ in my proof.

---

I know. it wrong since $g$ is change depend on $k$

Comment: why should $\int |f_k|^p$ be bounded for $k\to\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your dominating sequence to also converge in $L^p$ for the dominated convergence theorem to hold. Specifically, you need a convergent sequence $g_n(x)\geq f_n(x)$ and $\int g_n(x)$ needs to converge to $\int g$ use the dominated convergence theorem.

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\sqrt{n} 1_{0<x<1/n}$ in $L^2$. These clearly converge pointwise to $0$, the bound you've constructed in 2 is
$$|f_n(x)|^2\leq 4|f_n(x)|^2$$
which is vacuously true. But for every point in the sequence
$$ \int |f_n(x)|^2 =1,$$
so it does not converge to 0.